# Send responses to GET requests - ESP8266 as webserver

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I recently started working on a project in which I am using an ESP8266 to receive data from my computer or mobile phone. I do the following to set my ESP8266 as a server.

```
AT+CWMODE=2 //makes the module a AP
AT+CIPMUX=1 //enables multiple connections (needed for the next command)
AT+CIPSERVER=1,80 //starts a server and opens port 80
```

Now, incomming requests (going to the modules ip-adress in a webbrowser) will be send through the modules serial out:

```
IPD,0,412:GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168/4.1
```

My only issue is that the webbrowser will keep on loading, because it is not getting any response from the server it is trying to reach. I would like the module to be able to send an 'OK' back to the computer so it knows it doesn't have to resend its data. I have tried using

```
AT+CIPSEND=<id>,2,"OK"
```

but I haven't got any luck so far..

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to reply with a full HTTP header. Something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK<\r><\n>
Content-Length: 0<\r><\n>  
<\r><\n>
```

The TSP8266 doesn't seem to support HTTP, so you'll have to either send this response via UART for every connection or you write a firmware for the ESP8266 that has a (partly) functioning webserver.

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with electronics. It is programming :) RTFM! I even did not think that it can be that developer waits to load web page without implementing its sending from another side

Comment: That sounds logical, but my question remains: how would you do so? I have no idea how to send the data back to the computer.

Comment: Well if I put this on stackoverflow they will redirect me to electronics... but yeah, I will try.

Comment: Are you connected to the ESP via UART?

Comment: @MerijnDenHouting there's intersection of 3 directions: HTTP protocol if you are unsure what server should answer to client, ESP8266 programming if you do not know how to tackle chip's registers/commands, and physical connection of parts and interfacing, which is electronics. Where does your issue lie in? Probably you need to formulate question differently to get appropriate answer.

Comment: @FelixS i hooked it up to an arduino

Comment: @Anonymous yeah it's about the programming..

Comment: Then I'd wait for incoming HTTP connections and respond with AT+CIPSEND=0,[length of header in bytes]